# creating summary token for same donor but different categories

Tags: tokens, summaryfields

I'd like to send out to our donors a summary of all their contributions in the past year.

I am using a token that summarizes the total donation amount for the past year. The issue is we have different Types of donations and don't want them all summed up together. So the question is 
1. is there a way to get the sum only for specific transactions which i choose from the find contributions list
and if not
2. is there a way to save the tokens for different transaction types as different tokens and if so how?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [the summary fields extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields)?  I don't think it does exactly what you need out of the box but you can define additional fields using your own criteria with a little coding.